# Query for multilevel BOM in TEAMCENTER

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query which is working fine with 5 level test assembly. But the same query I used for the actual scenario. I went into loop again and again.

This is my query for multilevel BOM

```
WITH BOMTABLE AS (
SELECT parent_id, child_itemid, parenttype, childtype
  FROM FullBOM
  WHERE parent_id = '000022' 

UNION ALL

SELECT FB1.parent_id, FB1.child_itemid, FB1.parenttype, FB1.childtype
  FROM FullBOM FB1
  JOIN BOMTABLE ON FB1.parent_id = BOMTABLE.child_itemid
)

SELECT * FROM BOMTABLE
--ORDER BY child_itemid
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

How to stop the loop?
If anyone, please let me know.

Comment: We need a [mre], cos it's all down to your data.

Comment: You'll have to provide some sample data. Likely there's a cycle in your hierarchy, such as a parent_id referring to itself.

Comment: Add a level column counter and make sure the query max out on level 1000 or something like this. Then you can see which parent / child are repeating and fix your hierarchy

Comment: thanks for your response. but adding column level also didn't give the result